# Overfull vbox with scrbook and setspacing

Tags: vertical-alignment, koma-script, line-spacing, warnings, setspace

The following MWE gives me a lot of badbox warnings `Overfull \vbox (1.39674pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []` with always the same value of `1.39674pt`.
It seems to be related to the headline with the chapter title, which is displayed on every page but the first page of a chapter.

```
\documentclass[
    draft,
    headsepline=true
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Introduction}
  \Blindtext
  \chapter{Results}
  \Blindtext \Blindtext
  \section{Good results}
  \Blindtext \Blindtext
  \section{Mediocre results}
  \Blindtext \Blindtext
  \section{Bad results}
  \Blindtext \Blindtext
  \chapter{Conclusion}
  \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this and what is the recommended way to increase linespacing in the KOMA-script documentclasses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You changed the line space and don't recalculate the type are.

Use:

```
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\recalctypearea
```

To tell `typearea` (used by KOMA) that the linespace was changed.

Comment: This fixes the (annoying but invisible) box errors, but (at least for me) this also drastically changed to page margins (resulting in ~10% more pages!), which I expected to be unaffected by line spacing. Any way to fix/prevent this?