# Overfull vbox with koma and setspacing

Tags: vertical-alignment, koma-script, line-spacing, warnings, setspace

I had got the same problem as in this question: [Overfull vbox with scrbook and setspacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37330/overfull-vbox-with-scrbook-and-setspacing)

Adding `\recalctypearea` after `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` cleared the warnings, but I have a follow up question:

In my document I use `\singlespacing` twice. First inside `\begin{titlepage} ... \end{titlepage}` and later inside `\begin{multicols}{2} ... \end{multicols}`.

Should `\recalctypearea` be called after each of these uses? The `\begin{multicols}{2} ... \end{multicols}` does ***not*** fill a complete page (the titlepage of course does).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there a MWE that could show a real existing problem is missing. So I'll try a theoretical answer.

IMO, you should not recalculate the size of the typing area in this case.

Title pages usually have enough glue to compensate the half line that could cause an underfull `\vbox`. If not, you can add some glue, e.g., at the end of the title page using `\vspace*{0pt plus 0.5\baselineskip}`. You also could ignore a warning because of an underfull `\vbox` on the title page. Or you could use `\enlargethispage` to enlarge or even shrink the size of the title page.

And if you `multicols` environments do not fill a complete page. They just should be handled like other special displayed material too. You should add some glue before or after them. But you don't need to do so on your own. `multicol` already adds `\multicolsep` before (and after) a `multicols` environment. This default to `12pt plus 4pt minus 3pt` so it has enough glue.

With other words: If you do not get any underfull `\vbox` message, you don't need to do anything. If you get such messages and if you want to get rid of them, you can avoid them adding some extra glue or enlarging a page or use other usual methods of avoiding underfull `\vbox`es.